# How to use AWS API Gateway to strip parameters from URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created `/redirect` method with `GET` and I would like to pass URL with parameters to it like such:

`/redirect/https://example.com?param=1`

and then, strip parameters and respond with a redirect to:

`https://example.com`

That's a quite unusual situation as I see that most API requests relay on URL parameters and I intend to do the opposite. I'm conflicted if I should use Mock or Lambda.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want to pass the URL as a querystring parameter rather than a path parameter. I think that it would look something like this:

`GET /redirect?uri=https://example.com?param=1`

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const Location = decodeURIComponent(event.queryStringParameters.uri);
  return {
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: { Location },
  }
};
```

This should return a [302 Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) response with the redirect location, which should result in a browser redirect.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It still returned parameter with your code but I changed 2 line to: `const Uri = decodeURIComponent(event.queryStringParameters.uri); const Location = Uri.split('?')[0];` 

And it works like it should :)